# Lua module pushing C functions from DllMain

Tags: c++, c, lua

I've got damn big problem. As you know Lua allows making modules and you can load these modules with require() function from 5.1(previously loadlib).

```
#define LUA extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl

static int l_TestFunc(lua_State * L) 
{

    lua_pushboolean (L, 1); // return true

    return 1;
}

LUA luaopen_MyModule(lua_State *L)
{

    printf("test2");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, l_TestFunc);
    lua_setglobal(L, "TestFunc");

    return 1;
}
```

so in Lua you are just using `require("MyModule")` and everything works.(luaopen_* is entry point then)

But I need to use standard way(DllMain as entry point). I tried but it didn't work.
Got any ideas?

Comment: "*But I need to use standard way(DllMain as entry point).*" ... why?

Answer (score 0):

> But I need to use standard way(DllMain as entry point). I tried but it didn't work. Got any ideas?

DllMain is always going to be your entry point (if defined), but you can't use it to load your functions because *you have no Lua state to load them into there*.

When you run "require" in Lua code, the app executing that code (e.g. lua.exe) will load your DLL (invoking DllMain), then call `luaopen_MyModule` *passing in the Lua state* that executed the require statement. There's no way for your DllMain to have access to that state pointer...

---

...well, no *ordinary* way. You *could* work something out so that the host apps writes the memory location of the Lua state to some external location accessible to your DLL (registry, file, etc.) *before* loading your DLL. Your DLLMain could fetch the pointer register and it's functions into that state. Not sure why you'd want to do that, but in a language like C it's technically possible.

This would require that you wrote the host, so you could arrange to write the state somewhere. Or you could have a separate module, loaded the ordinary way, which writes the Lua_state value, then all other modules could access it from their DllMains.

---

This smells a lot like an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). Care to share *why* you want to register your functions in DllMain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Instead of using the name MyModule in `require("MyModule")` and `luaopen_MyModule` use the name of the executable that your DLL is injected into. If that doesn't work change the require call to have `.exe` at the end.

Lua's require is going to call Win32 LoadLibrary and then GetProcAddress to find the luaopen function. Both calls will use the argument to require(). It appears that PE-inject makes all the functions in the injected DLL appear as if they are in the EXE module. So, you need LoadLibrary to return the handle to the EXE module and then GetProcAddress will find the injected luaopen function.

The are a few reasons this might not work. One is that Lua's require does have the requirement that the DLL file name and the DLL module name match. That's not a Win32 requirement and so might not be the case for your portable executable.