# Can a C++ dll file be loaded in Lua?

Tags: c++, dll, lua

I need to load a DLL file in Lua to connect different APIs. I know that C type dlls can be loaded, but what I have is a dll file produced in C++.

The code (in C++) that produced this library was of the form:

```
// MyAPI.h

namespace MyAPI
{
    public class MyFirstClass
    {
        public: 
           MyFirstClass();
           void performSomeMethod(int arg);
    }
}
```

which then produced the dll file `MyAPI.dll`. When I now try to import this in Lua, using:

```
require "MyAPI"
```

it immediately gives the error: `error loading module 'MyAPI' from file '.\MyAPI.dll': The specified procedure could not be found`. I do not understand what this means, or how to get rid of it. Can C++ libraries in general not be included by Lua (i.e. should I write another C wrapper?) or is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Expose a C-function loader `luaopen_MyAPI`, where you can call a function that uses any kind of C++ Lua Wrapper, such as [LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge), [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html) or others. If your calls in C++ don't conform to the rules of the bindings, such as lifetime management, passing objects by value, etc, you might need to wrap the classes into bindable classes.

For an example see [pugilua](https://github.com/d-led/pugilua/tree/master/pugilua)

- pugilua_lib.h - module loader API
- pugilua_lib.cpp - wrapper classes and a LuaBridge binding
- pugilua.cpp - calling the bindings from the module loader

Comment: @Yellow glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to export a C function named `luaopen_ MyAPI` that follows the C-Lua API. The rest of the code can be C++.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you will need to have a C wrapper with a C entry point rather than a C++ entry point.  C++ does name mangling so it can change dynamically depending on the compiler as well as the method signature, etc.

Here is [Anatomy of a Lua to C Call](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm) which you may find helpful.

Also see this [stack overflow discussion on what goes on with dll loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844908/lua-module-pushing-c-functions-from-dllmain).

And here is another [stack overflow discussion on require and dll loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058186/how-do-i-extend-lua-with-a-static-c-library).

This is a [brief post on the name mangling problem](http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Please-suggest-me-where-am-I-wrong-require-function-of-lua-is-failing-td7646906.html).